# Study of a map between completions

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let be R a ring and let $f:R[\! [ X_1, ..., X_n ]\! ]\rightarrow R[\! [ X_1, ..., X_n ]\! ]$ an homomorfism of $R$-algebras. Called $J\in M_{n\times n}(R)$ the jacobian matrix $J=\left( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial X_j}(0)\right)$ where $f_i:=f(X_i)$. Show that $f$ is an isomorfism iff det$(J)$ is invertible in $R$.

I've tried in this way but i have some doubts.

Called $A:=R[\! [x_1, ..., x_n]\! ]$. I observe that $f$ induce a map called $J_f$ on $\Omega_{A/R}$:

$$
\begin{array}
&A \longrightarrow & A \\
\downarrow &\downarrow\\
\Omega_{A/R} \longrightarrow &\Omega_{A/R}
\end{array}
$$

I've got that $J_f(d_A(x_i))=d_A(f(x_i))=d_A(f_i)=\Sigma_{j=1...n} \partial f_i/\partial x_j dx_j$. I observe that $J_f$ is linear so can be rapresented by a matrix $J$ that send $dx_i\to df_i$ so it's the jacobian matrix. Now i'm stucked.

Comment: Can you do this for $n=1$?

Comment: I find out that for n=1 is similar to a theorem that i found in Eisenbud. But the main problem is that $f_i=f(x_i)$ are not necessary $f_i\in \mathfrak(m)$

Comment: Can you show that every map as you describe must have $f_i\in m$? Again, can you do this for $n=1$? For instance, can you show that there are no such maps with $x\mapsto 1$ in one variable case?